# How can I identify when a copy process in node.js is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This are my first steps with node.js. I will watch a directory with **chokidar** for added files. If the copy process is finished a script should be called. But I don't know how can I identify when the copy process is finished and the file is complete available on my directory. The console log command with the word **finish** never appear.

```
var fs       = require('fs');
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var watcher = chokidar.watch('/root/Documents/gw/', {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});

watcher
   .on('add', function(path) {

    console.log('File', path, 'has been added');

    fs.watchFile(path, function(curr, prev) {

      if (curr.size == prev.size) {
          console.log('finish');
          // TODO start a shell script 
      } else                     {
          console.log(curr.size);
      }
    });
});
```

I use node.js version 0.10.25 on a Linux system.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Save as eq file.TMP then use another function to rename to image extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your test will never be positive is that on a simple copy operation `fs.watchFile` won't generate an event where the previous size is going to be equal to the current size. For this to happen, there would have to be a *change* to the file, because `fs.watchFile` fire only on *changes*. But in a straightforward copy operation there typically won't be a file change occurring where the previous size and the current size are the same.

Here's a solution that detects when a file has stopped changing after a set timeout:

```
var fs       = require('fs');
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var watcher = chokidar.watch('dir', {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});

var end_timeout = 30000;

watcher
    .on('add', function(path) {

        console.log('File', path, 'has been added');

        fs.stat(path, function (err, stat) {
            // Replace error checking with something appropriate for your app.
            if (err) throw err;
            setTimeout(checkEnd, end_timeout, path, stat);
        });
});

function checkEnd(path, prev) {
    fs.stat(path, function (err, stat) {

        // Replace error checking with something appropriate for your app.
        if (err) throw err;
        if (stat.mtime.getTime() === prev.mtime.getTime()) {
            console.log("finished");
            // Move on: call whatever needs to be called to process the file.
        }
        else
            setTimeout(checkEnd, end_timeout, path, stat);
    });
}
```

Note that if the directory is prepopulated with files, this code will start watching them right away. I can imagine use-case scenarios where this is desirable and some where it is not.

Comment: Thank you for this - really helped me.